# Threaded function not catching ANY exceptions in try-catch block

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

So I have this function, designed to download YouTube videos from the internet.

However whenever I run it, it does not catch ***any*** exception. Even an explicitly thrown new exception().

*It's a WPF program so before anyone mentions bad coding etiquette, please don't. I'm more concerned with getting my program working at the moment.*

Here's the code that creates the thread:

```
void button1_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.IsEnabled = false;
            this.downloadProgressText.Text = "Beginning....";
            int selectedIndex = this.queueListView.SelectedIndex;
            Thread newThread = new Thread (() => Download_Handler(classContainer, 0, selectedIndex, 0));
            newThread.Start();
        }
```

And the threaded function itself:

```
private void Download_Handler (ClassContainer classCont, int curVidPosition, int selectedIndex, int retryCount)
        {
            ObservableCollection<Video> finishedUrls = new ObservableCollection<Video> ();
            ObservableCollection<Video> urlList = videoQueue.Items;
            for (int position = curVidPosition, urlListCount = urlList.Count; position < urlListCount; position++)
            {
                try
                {
                    downloadProgressText.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateSelectedListItemCallback (this.UpdateSelectedListItem), new object[] {
                        position
                    });
                    Video vid = urlList [position];

                    if (classCont.DownloadingCode.DownloadVideo(vid, this, position) != null)
                    {
                        finishedUrls.Add(vid);
                    }

                    if (finishedUrls != null && finishedUrls.Count > 0)
                    {
                        classCont.IOHandlingCode.WriteUrlsToFile(finishedUrls, true);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    var exceptionMessage = ex.Message;

                    if (retryCount <= 4)
                    {

                        downloadProgressText.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateProgressBarCallback (this.UpdateProgressBar), new object[] {
                            string.Format(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, "URL {0}: {1}. Retrying.... ({2}/{3})", position + 1, classContainer.ConversionCode.Truncate(exceptionMessage, 50), retryCount.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture), "3"),
                            -1
                        });

                        Thread.Sleep(850);

                        Download_Handler(classCont, position, selectedIndex, retryCount + 1);

                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        if (finishedUrls.Count < 10)
                        {

                            finishedUrls.Clear();

                        }
                        downloadProgressText.Dispatcher.Invoke(new UpdateProgressBarCallback (this.UpdateProgressBar), new object[] {
                            classCont.ConversionCode.Truncate(exceptionMessage, 100),
                            -1
                        });
                    }

                }
            }
            videoQueue.Items = finishedUrls.Count > 0 ? (ObservableCollection<Video>)urlList.Where(video => finishedUrls.All(item => item != video)).Select(video => video) : urlList;

            if (this.queueListView.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                this.RefreshQueue(videoQueue.Items, selectedIndex < this.queueListView.Items.Count ? 0 : selectedIndex);
            }
            this.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

This coding scheme worked just fine in WinForms (well, with slight differences), but since the move to WPF I just **cannot** figure it out!

EDIT:

Including additional code:

```
public Video DownloadVideo (Video video, MainWindow MainForm, int position)
        {   
            MainForm.Dispatcher.Invoke(new MainWindow.UpdateProgressBarCallback (MainForm.UpdateProgressBar), new object[] {
                0,
                string.Format(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, "Beginning download from '{0}'", video.Location)
            });

            /*
            * Get the available video formats.
            * We'll work with them in the video and audio download examples.
            */
            IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos = DownloadUrlResolver.GetDownloadUrls(video.Location, false);

            if ((video.Format != VideoType.Mp4 && videoInfos.Any(info => (info.Resolution == video.Resolution && info.VideoType == video.Format)) || video.Format == VideoType.Mp4 && video.Resolution == 360))
            {

                VideoInfo currentVideo = videoInfos.First(info => info.VideoType == video.Format && info.Resolution == video.Resolution);

                MainForm.Dispatcher.Invoke(new MainWindow.UpdateProgressBarCallback (MainForm.UpdateProgressBar), new object[] {
                    -1,
                    string.Format(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, "Downloading '{0}{1}' at {2}p resolution", Conversion.Truncate(currentVideo.Title, 56), currentVideo.VideoExtension, currentVideo.Resolution)
                });

                //DownloadAudio(videoInfos);
                this.Download_Actual(videoInfos, MainForm, video.Resolution, position, video.Format);
                return video;
            }


            if (videoInfos.Where(info => info.VideoType == video.Format).All(info => info.Resolution != video.Resolution) || (video.Format == VideoType.Mp4 && video.Resolution != 360))
            {       
                List<int> resolutionsEstablished = new List<int> ();
                List<VideoType> formatsEstablished = new List<VideoType> ();
                using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter ("Acceptable Options.txt"))
                {
                    outfile.Write(string.Format(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, "This file will show you all formats available for the current URL, as well as the resolutions that are acceptable for that URL.\n\n{0}:\n", video.Location));

                    foreach (VideoType format in videoInfos.Where(info => info.VideoType != VideoType.Unknown && formatsEstablished.All(format => info.VideoType != format)).Select(info => info.VideoType))
                    {       
                        if (format == VideoType.Mp4)
                        {
                            outfile.Write(string.Format(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, "Format: {0} | Resolution: {1}p\n", format, "360"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (int resolution in videoInfos.Where(info => info.Resolution >= 144 && info.Resolution < 720 && resolutionsEstablished.All(res => info.Resolution != res) && info.VideoType == format).Select(info => info.Resolution))
                            {           
                                outfile.Write(string.Format(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, "Format: {0} | Resolution: {1}p\n", format, resolution));

                                resolutionsEstablished.Add(resolution); 
                            }
                        }
                        resolutionsEstablished.Clear();
                        formatsEstablished.Add(format);
                    }
                }
                throw new NotSupportedException("An acceptable options file has been exported to the program's root folder. Check there for more information.");
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void Download_Actual (IEnumerable<VideoInfo> videoInfos, MainWindow MainForm, int resolution, int position, VideoType format)
        {
            /*
             * Select the first .mp4 video with 360p resolution
             */
            VideoInfo video = videoInfos
                .First(info => info.VideoType == format && info.Resolution == resolution);

            /*
             * If the video has a decrypted signature, decipher it
             */
            if (video.RequiresDecryption)
            {
                DownloadUrlResolver.DecryptDownloadUrl(video);
            }

            /*
             * Create the video downloader.
             * The first argument is the video to download.
             * The second argument is the path to save the video file.
             */

            Settings settings = Storage.ReadFromRegistry();
            var videoName = RemoveIllegalPathCharacters(video.Title) + video.VideoExtension;
            var videoPath = Path.Combine(settings.TemporarySaveLocation, videoName);
            var finalPath = Path.Combine(settings.MainSaveLocation, videoName);

            if (!File.Exists(finalPath))
            {
                var videoDownloader = new VideoDownloader (video, videoPath);

                // Register the ProgressChanged event and print the current progress
                videoDownloader.DownloadProgressChanged += (
                    (sender, args) => MainForm.downloadProgressBar.Dispatcher.Invoke(new MainWindow.UpdateProgressBarCallback (MainForm.UpdateProgressBar), new object[] {
                    (int)args.ProgressPercentage,
                    null
                })
                );

                /*
                 * Execute the video downloader.
                 * For GUI applications note, that this method runs synchronously.
                 */
                videoDownloader.Execute();

                File.Move(videoPath, finalPath);
            }
            else
            {
                MainForm.downloadProgressText.Dispatcher.Invoke(new MainWindow.UpdateProgressBarCallback (MainForm.UpdateProgressBar), new object[] {
                    0,
                    null
                });
                throw new FieldAccessException("{0}({1}) already exists! Download process has been aborted and considered successful.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line is causing the exception. I would guess the exception is being thrown from within the catch block or after the whole try/catch block

Comment: Any of them, but it happens with the child function "classCont.DownloadingCode.DownloadVideo" the most. However, as mentioned, I put a "throw new exception()" right at the start of the try block, and it wasn't caught.

Comment: What is the exception type that is thrown if you don't throw new Exception()? Might give a clue to the problem....

Comment: It's a socket exception. I know exactly why it was thrown. I use peerblock (I know, placebo, etc) and when it's enabled the program can't reach the server, causing it to go a little crazy and throw exceptions all over the place. That said, the whole point of the try-catch block is to catch ANY error so the user can continue to use the program. The error itself is of no consequence unless it causes the program to be inoperable which, if handled correctly, this one would not.

Comment: I asked which exception type it was as some exceptions can't be handled e.g. StackOverflowException.

Comment: I'm guessing you have already tried putting a breakpoint into the first line of the catch? And does it hit the breakpoint?

Comment: System.SocketException. I also get "System.NotSupportedException" rather often too, which is a handled exception I explicitly throw.

Comment: And no, it does not. At least I don't think so. The debugger doesn't mention a breakpoint.

Comment: So, it is catching the exceptions then... So what happens within the Catch block?

Your problem may be related to using ObservableCollection in a background thread. I'm not sure if this is supported. Could you switch to List<Video>?

Comment: It looks to me like the ObservableCollections are created on the UI thread and then the background thread is attempting to access them. I would expect this to throw an exception.

Comment: I know you stated no preaching, but if you cleaned this up with a BackgroundWorker or other threading pattern you would find this a lot easier and get it to work a lot faster, hacking always digs a hole that difficult to get out of. Trust me I've been there.

Comment: No, it's not the ObservableCollection. Exceptions are still thrown even though they should not be.

Comment: I'm trying to recreate your scenario. What type is videoQueue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84516/discussion-between-glen-thomas-and-user3375027).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was ***really*** stupid of a mistake....

So I call `public delegate void UpdateProgressBarCallback (int progress, string message);` to update text and progress bar values.

In this case, in the catch block, I was attempting to pass as the other way around, IE `public delegate void UpdateProgressBarCallback (string message, int progress);`. THAT'S why it was being weird. It all works now.

Comment: It's good you got this to work. But if you plan to make changes, you should use [async/await](http://msdn.com/async) for I/O, not threads. Threads have considerable overhead, and run orders of magnitude faster than I/O, so a thread used for I/O will block immediately.

Comment: Well, it does more than just I/O operations, and I need to not block UI while it works. However, along with other suggestions I've gotten, I'll take it under advisement.

Answer (score 3):

I've stripped your code back to basics and works fine for me. Would probably need a complete code sample

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Thread newThread = new Thread(Download_Handler);
    newThread.Start();
}

private void Download_Handler()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: While this does in fact work for me, it does not solve my main problem. Though it raises a significant amount of questions.